# Trying to get Task Id of a Fargate Launch Type Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to get the `TaskId` for logging purposes. I am following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html). I have added the environment variable:

```
ECS_ENABLE_CONTAINER_METADATA='true'
```

Then I do a `GET ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4/task`. I've printed out the URL which gives me something like: `http://169.254.170.2/v4/2e04c299-bfac-41b2-b4ee-76ac7a8d8f71/task`.

But my response gives me a `403`. Do I need to generate an AWS Signature Version 4 with the request? I do have a proxy defined could that be a problem, I am now trying to add `169.254.170.2` to the no proxy if that does anything, has anyone been successful calling this endpoint?

I've also added:

`no_proxy & NO_PROXY=169.254.169.254,169.254.170.2,/var/run/docker.sock` as seen [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/http-proxy-docker-ecs/). But that link is for `ec2` container instances, I am using Farget. Still seem to be getting the dreaded `403`.

Comment: Did you make sure your Fargate engine version is 1.4.0? It needs to be set manually.. Selecting latest in the console/Cloudformation defaults to 1.3.0.

Comment: OMG you were right lol I was using cloudformation with the platform version of `latest` I assumed that would give me the latest version haha I wouldn't have thought it would selected 1.3.0, but when I checked my service it was using the older version. If you put this as an answer I can accept so you get more points?

Comment: I still get 403 though lol

Comment: I think your taskrole, or taskexecutionrole, doesn't have enough permissions to query the endoint, hence the 403 error.